# Cannot cancel animation in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am aware of `ViewExtensions.CancelAnimations(view);`. I've tried it. It doesn't work.

I have raised this issue on the [Xamarin Forms Github repo](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10706), in the meantime I'm hoping someone can offer a workaround.

I am trying to create a scale animation on a Label that is started and stopped by a ViewModel property. I have create two simple `TriggerAction<VisualElement>` to start and stop

```
public class StartAnimationAction : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
    public Animation Animation { set; get; }

    protected override void Invoke(VisualElement view)
    {
        this.Animation.Commit(view, "ScaleIt", length: 30000, easing: Easing.Linear,
                finished: (v, c) => view.Scale = 1, repeat: () => false);
    }
}

public class StopAnimationAction : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
    protected override void Invoke(VisualElement view)
    {
        ViewExtensions.CancelAnimations(view);
    }
}
```

The animation property on the StartAction is set via the View

```
var throbAnimation = new Animation(v => this.MyLabel.Scale = v, 1, 2);
```

The ViewModel is done with a DataTrigger

```
<Label x:Name="MyLabel" Text="Hello World">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding IsSyncing}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <settings:StartAnimationAction x:Name="StartAnimation"/>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <settings:StopAnimationAction/>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

The ViewExtensions.CancelAnimations does not stop the animation and the callback and repeat callbacks continue to be called.

Are there other ways to cancel an animation or am I incorrectly using CancelAnimations?

Comment: try calling this on main thread `Device.BeginInvokeonMainThread(()=> ViewExtensions.CancelAnimation(label)`

Comment: That made no difference at all :-(

Comment: Could it work ?

Comment: Sorry for not coming back sooner. Your answer @LeoZhu-MSFT worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you achieved the animation by calling the `Commit` method,you could cancel the animation with a call to the `AbortAnimation` extension method.

change

```
public class StopAnimationAction : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
  protected override void Invoke(VisualElement view)
  {
    ViewExtensions.CancelAnimations(view);
  }
}
```

to

```
public class StopAnimationAction : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
    protected override void Invoke(VisualElement view)
    {
      view.AbortAnimation("ScaleIt");//the name you commit in startAnimationAciton
    }
}
```